# Quartz .Net resume after application restart

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, quartz

I have quartz working with MS SQL, it stores all the job detail in sql but I don't know how to set it up to resume all the jobs after application restart.

can anyone please let me know how setup quartz to resume jobs after application restart.

This is what I do to schedule a job on api call

```
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Temp\test.txt",$"Starting sechd at {DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss")}");
            ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            IScheduler sc = sf.GetScheduler();
            sc.Start();
            IJobDetail emailJob = JobBuilder.Create<EmailJob>()
         .WithIdentity("reportemail", "reportgroup")
         .Build();
            string dom = js.DayOfMonth.ToString();
            if (js.DayOfWeek > 0)
                dom = "?";
            string dow = (js.DayOfWeek < 1) ? "*" : js.DayOfWeek.ToString();
            string y = (js.Year > 0) ? js.Year.ToString() : "*";
            string m = (js.Month > 0) ? js.Month.ToString() : "*";
            string crn = $"{js.Second.ToString()} {js.Minute.ToString()} {js.Hour.ToString()} {dom} {m} {dow} {y}"; 
            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                 .ForJob(emailJob)
                 .WithIdentity("reporttrigger","reportgroup")
                 .WithCronSchedule("0 0/3 * ? * *")
                 .StartNow()
                 .Build();

            sc.ScheduleJob(emailJob, trigger);
```

Thanks

Comment: read up on "Misfire Instructions" https://dzone.com/articles/quartz-scheduler-misfire . You can set it up so that if for any reason an invocation is missed it will be retried.

Answer (score 0):

Im currently using Quartz.Net in my MVC application, and what I have done is in my JobScheducler.cs I have a method called "Start" where I have placed all the code, for the schedules I want to be run on application start.

In Global.asax I have instantiated the JobScheduler and I then call the start method, which in turn. Starts all of the schedules I've set up to be run.